# Alignment issues with css

Tags: html, css

Anyone see why my footer is all shifted over with the image as well as the links and copyright isn't showing as it should?

http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/

mockup:
http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/assets/images/wrestling2.jpg

Comment: Can you post the original pertinent source code into the this question?  Otherwise, this question isn't useful to any other user.

Comment: I agree with KatieK; although this whole thing might be too localized to be of any benefit to anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because line #58 of v1.css floats the whole thing left.

Comment: Only thing is how am I going to add a | inbetween each of the LI's?

Comment: @Mr.Magoo, That's a separate issue entirely, but can easily be solved by adding a right border to each `<li>`.  Have a `class="last"` or whatever for the last one, where you can set the right border to `none`.

Answer (score 2):

You are floating your `<li>` elements to the left.

Remove the float left and change the css on these to `display: inline` and it will look much more like your mock up.

Answer (score 1):

```
#footer ul {
list-style: none outside none;
margin-left: 40%;
text-align: center;}
```